# Find the natural numbers so that $n=2a^2 ,n=3b^3 ,n=5c^5$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Well here it is i spend almost 3 hours on this one!! Find the general form of the natural numbers that are twice a square  ,tripple of a cube and 5 times a 5-ith power.Who is the smaller of them?.What  i understood is .Find natural numbers so that $n=2 a^2$, $n=3 b^3$,  $n=5 c^5$  where $a,b,c$ natural numbers.! My progress so far is that i took the canonical form for a supposed $N$ also said that $2, 3, 5$  must be in the prime factorization and also used a lemma where it says for a number $A$ to be a $n$-th power of number all of the power's from its prime factorization  must be divisible by that power.So what I got is $n$ to be $n=2^{z_1} \cdot 3^{z_2} \cdot 5^{z_5} \cdot \dotsb \cdot p_k^{z_i}$.... where $z_1>=15$ and $z_1-1$ is even  $z_2>=10$ and $z_2=3k+1$, $z_3>=6$ and $z_3=5l+1$ and the rest $z_i$ must be of the form $30 h_i$!That is all, I'm kinda lost and don't know how to continue and corner it so i get a complete for and not a so general one.Help please.(the $z_i$ are the power's of the prime numbers in the prime factorization)

Comment: The "shortest" description is $2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^4 \cdot m^{30}$.

Comment: Please try to make the post more readable by using appropriate spacing.Also,try to make the title more informative.And if you can,try to format the question properly.It is laudable that you have shown your own effort.

Comment: why 2*(3^2)*(5^4)*(m^30)???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smallest such number is clearly of the form $2^a3^b5^c$, and once you work out the values of $a,b,c$ that work then whatever number $n$ you get as a minimal solution, you will have that $n m^{30}$ is also a solution for any $m \geq 1$. This characterizes all solutions by the Chinese remainder theorem.

To figure out the valid smallest power of $2$, note that the power $a$ must be odd because your number is $2$ times a square. Furthermore $a$ must be divisible by $3$ and $5$. So $a$ is an odd number divisible by $15$. So the smallest possible $a$ is $15$. Similarly you can work out the conditions on $b$ and figure out that $b = 10$, and that $c = 6$. Thus the set of all solutions is $2^{15}3^{10}5^6 m^{30}$ for any $m \geq 1$, and the smallest such solution is when $m = 1$.

Comment: i have found those things already but didnt know that's all.I had found that the numbers are of the form 2^(15*k)*3^(10*l)*5^(6*i)*(p*q...z)(30*a)  where k, l ,i,a are nutral number's and p, q,...z are primes .Is it ok to say p*q..*z=1 ???

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis For the smallest positive example, yes it is ok to say that there are no primes in the factorization other than $2,3,5$.